# What is the best syntax for checking for null value objects in C#

Tags: c#

It always feels wrong to me to write

```
if (MyObject)
    // do something
```

Or reversly

```
if (!MyObject)
    // do something
```

However you could argue that it is less verbose than

```
if (MyObject != null)
    // do something

if (MyObject == null)
    // do something
```

Are there any **non-subjective** reasons to use one over the other?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In C#, you can't do

```
if (MyObject)
```

to check for `null`s. It's a compile time error (if the class doesn't have an implicit boolean conversion operator).

```
if (!MyObject)
```

is also invalid if the class doesn't overload `operator !` to return a boolean value (or a value that can be implicitly casted to a boolean).

So you have to stick with `obj == null` and `obj != null`.

To summarize, the non-subjective reason is being able to compile your code!

#### UPDATE (story):

Once upon a time, in ancient C, there was no `bool` type. Zero was considered `false` and every non-zero value was considered `true`. You could write

```
while(1) { }
```

to create an infinite loop.
You could also do things like

```
int n  = 10;
while (n--) { }
```

to have a loop that executes `n` times. The problem with this strategy was:

```
int x = 10;
if (x = 0) { // bug: meant to be x == 0
}
```

You missed a single character and you created a bug (most modern C compilers will issue a warning on this statement, but it's valid C, nevertheless).

This is why you see code like

```
if (5 == variable) 

if (NULL == pObj)
```

in many places as it's not prone to the above mistake.

C# designers decided to **require** a *boolean* expression as the condition for `if`, `while`, etc., and not allow casting of types (unless they explicitly declare an overloaded operator, which is discouraged) to boolean to reduce the chance of errors. So things like:

```
object x = null;
if (x) { }

int y = 10;
if (y) { }
while (y--) { }
```

that are valid in C, **do not compile in C# at all**.
This is not a matter of style or agreement by any means.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any non-subjective reasons
>   to use one over the other?

The fact that (1) and (2) don't compile is a non-subjective reason enough to not use them.

So we are left with (3) and (4):

```
if (MyObject != null)
    // do something

if (MyObject == null)
    // do something
```

Here it depends on whether you want to do something if MyObject is null (4), or if it is not null (3). **Clearly this is not a style choice.** It would be ridiculous to adopt always the same "style", because then if you wanted the *other* condition you'd have to do:

```
    if (MyObject == null) // style policy
    {
        // nothing here
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Which isn't exactly what I'd call readable code.

Answer (score 2):

In my mind, a bit of verbosity in this case is a *good* thing. That would be the case if you were allowed to do both, which isn't in fact possible, as Mehrdad points out. The "implicit" null check (i.e. `if (MyObject)`) does not even compile in C#.

```
if (MyObject == null)
    // do something
```

This is however quite similar to the situation of checking with an integer is greater than 0. The two equivalent options here (that both compile and run fine in C but *not* C#, unless I'm mistaken) are:

```
if (myInt)
    // do something
```

and

```
if (myInt > 0)
    // do something
```

I always go for the second option here, purely for clarity (it can't be mistaken for a bool!), though you will quite often see the former "implicit" check in code.

Comment: Don't they do it in reverse like this - if (null == MyObject) //do something

?

Comment: The implicit check if (MyObject) is better to check for boolean values only.

Comment: @Kirtan: That's a left-over from C syntax, where you could accidentally assign null to MyObject instead of equating it (by only using a single =). There's no risk of ding this in C#.

Comment: No, it's not equivalent. You *can't* say `if (myInt)` in C#. It's not an issue of style and agreement. It's a semantic *rule* in C#.

Comment: I like to do it this way instead of if(myObject)because it is more immediately clear that you are checking for null and not checking MyObject as a bool for true or false.

Kirtan, you can do it both ways. I would put the null first if we were doing a few of these checks against different objects. Such as
     if (null==MyObject1)else if(null==myObject2) ... 

I would out my Object first if the 'paragraph of code' was 'about' myobject, and put null first if it was 'about' null, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yep, corrected as soon as I saw your post. Always wise to check the code an asker posts does in fact compile! I think the "if (myInt > 0)" analogy, which actually works, is however worth pointing out.

Comment: @Noldorin: No, it doesn't compile either. Specifically, C# designers decided not to allow any integral type to be casted implicitly to boolean so that you couldn't accidentally say `if (x = 0)`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah, so where am I thinking this is possible? C# 2.0 perhaps? VB.NET? I know I've successfully done that somewhere before.

Comment: you can't do "if (myInt)" in C#, you can in C, but not in C#.

Comment: @Noldorin: I'm sure it has not been possible in C# since the very beginning. It's valid in VB.NET and C++, though.

Comment: @Lasse: Thanks - I knew I'd seen it somewhere. Not sure why I deserved the downvote however, given that I was searching for clarification!

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah, that would make sense. I've done a lot of VB.NET and C too, so it's easy enough to get muddled over this.

Comment: @Noldorin - Even in C, `myInt` and `myInt > 0` are not equivalent: `if (myInt)` is equal to `if (myInt != 0)` not greater than 0. `if (-1) { printf("hello"); }` would print "hello".

Comment: @Mehrdad: You really are a true pedant! My last message was a cue to *stop* this discussion, since it's going precisely nowhere. :)

Answer (score 2):

In C#, an if statement requires a boolean expression.

So, in your example above using `if(myObject)` to test for null is actually wrong. You'd need to do the more verbose `if(myObject==null)`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon personal preferences. Ideally, in C#, to check for `null`, the following syntax is used -

```
if (MyObject != null)
    //Do Something.
```

Comment: Says who, and why? The above is a purely personal preference, it's neither standard in C# nor is their a technical reason to corroborate this (in C#!).

Comment: This may be ideal in C, but it's mostly frowned upon in C#; use this in your own code, but don't force others to reverse their logic for no reason. To me, that piece of code reads: "if null is not equal to something". But I already know the value of null, it's null! Why would I want to find out if null has changed? I want to know "if something is not equal to null" - so I do: if (MyObject != null).

Comment: Writing the boolean expression like this makes it harder to read (it doesn't logically flow like a sentence). As others have said, this style of writing null checks is not helpful at all in C#.

Answer (score 1):

And if you just want to set a default value to an object if it is null, you can use the c# 3.0 ?? operator.

the code:

```
MyType _myObject
if (SomeObject==null)
  _myObject = defaultObjectValue
else
  _myObject = SomeObject
```

can be writen as

```
_myObject = SomeObject ?? defaultObjectValue;
```

which basically means that if SomeObject exists, use it, and if it does not, use the default value.

Comment: ?? is also known as "Coalescing Operator". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3F_Operator